# How do I prepare for technical and behavioral interviews at Google?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, united-states

I'm a senior computer science student about to graduate from university (in the US). Google approached me about the possibility of a full-time position upon graduation in May. Long story short, I've made it to the final round, which is a series of on-site interviews at Google HQ in Mountain View, CA.

I've gone through an experience like this twice before, one for another different position I'm considering in Washington, DC (for which I've already received an offer), and a few years ago when I landed a summer internship for another massive tech company. I've also worked several other internships and full-time positions in technical roles.

The Google position is for a semi-technical role like the one I had at the other large technology company, so the interviews will be a mix of technical interviews as well as behavioral interviews. In total, there will be 4 one-hour interviews as well as an hour-long lunch interview.

General interview advice aside, **how can I best prepare for both technical and behavioral interviews at Google?** I've done many (relative to my age) technical interviews before, but Google interviews are supposed to be notoriously challenging.

Comment: Did you ask your recruiter? When I went through this last year they sent me a bunch of resources for preparing and even had mock interview sessions available.

Comment: @Rob Google is great first gig out of college. A lot of tech companies are copying Google and want a certain fit for the company. They want you to eat, sleep, and breathe in google and work there 24/7 if you have to. They got beds, kitchens, gyms, you name it.

Comment: @Dan - There are also people here (W.SE) whom say that they want their pound of flesh for their money. I've worked at a *lot* of companies where you are **not** allowed to smoke, because it's illegal; does that mean they'll let you smoke, you bet it does. Is it the same for the owner fetching and delivering beer, need you ask? -- Inexpensive *luxury* and 'everyone is your pal' are the life and breathe of some companies (like Wal-Mart) others are brutal (Bayer, Toyota in North America, less so elsewhere). 24/7 is wonderful if paid 5x wages, and two days a week; time to spend your riches.

Comment: @whrrgarbl Indeed, I did ask and the recruiter sent a number of resources to help both understand the role and prepare for the technical interviews (e.g. _Cracking the Coding Interview_), but nothing about mock interviews. I'm waiting on another TBD call with the recruiter to help answer some specific questions. Wish I could pick your brain some time regarding your experience!

Comment: @Rob I too have some reservations about their pay, especially given the position would be in the SF Bay area. I think my other offer, which is still high for a new grad, would allow me more flexibility and to stretch my wages further.

Comment: Ok that's good, really their info is going to be the most accurate. If you've interviewed with any of the other big-name companies (e.g. MS, Amazon) it's pretty much the same style. My experience with the technical interviews was that it was "the usual" and their prep materials set appropriate expectations for content - just felt like a marathon by the end of the day.

Comment: @Rob I appreciate the research! Based on my own, I expect a potential offer to be ~$110k/yr (with $30k-$50k additional in RSUs, annual vesting over 4 years). I neglected to mention I will be married in June, and with that I mind I foresee rent in the Bay area within walking/Google bus distance being $3500-$4500 a month (ABSURDLY high!) for a slightly larger 1-2 bedroom apartment. Of course, initially, my then-wife can work as well to help support the higher housing costs. The other offer I have is for DC, and it's definitely competitive for the region. Tough choices.

Comment: This says you'll want U$180K for San Fran but only U$105 for DC, so if the other place pays the same you're way ahead ($/competition/COL and DC will get *stuff* before the other end of the country does). See: https://dc.curbed.com/2017/7/14/15973934/dc-salary-apartment-report .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just be yourself in the interview. If you pretend to be anyone else, either they'll see through it or you'll get the job and not like it because you're pretending.

In any long interview like this, remember that you're being interviewed 100% of the time.

Comment: The long interviews get pretty intense! Great reminder to always stay professional and friendly the whole time. Thanks for the advice, PeteCon!

Comment: Marking this answer as correct given that it appears my question was put on hold/closed as primarily opinion-based.